# Further on determinants and finding the second partial derivative

Tags: determinant, partial-derivative

Below is the question:

> $$\begin{cases} 
>      v+log\left|u\right|=xy \\
>      u+log\left|v\right|=x-y
>   \end{cases}\implies
>   \begin{cases}
>      \frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=y \\
>      \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=1
>   \end{cases}\implies
> \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
> yu & u \\
> v & 1 \\
> \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} 1 & u \\ v & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix}}=\frac{u\left(y-v\right)}{1-uv}$$

and this is the equivalent of the first partial derivative. Now I have to find $\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}}$. I think it looks like:

> $$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{u\left(y-v\right)}{1-uv}\right)=\frac{\left(1-uv\right)\left(u\left(-1\right)+\left(y-u\right)\right)-u\left(y-u\right)\left(-v\right)}{\left(1-uv\right)^2}$$
>   $$=\boxed{\frac{\left(1-uv\right)\left(y-2u\right)+\left(yuv-vu^2\right)}{\left(1-uv^2\right)}}$$

Am I right? Or do I have to do a determinant like they did (even if I am right, how would you solve this using a determinant?).
Thank you,
Brandon

Comment: If you apply another derivative to your system you get equations with "extra" terms like $-\frac{1}{u^2}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2$ which make your method not applicable. I do not understand your result: when you apply the second derivative to the ration $\frac{u(y-v)}{1-uv}$ why don't you write any derivative on the r.h.s.?

Comment: Probably because I'm not doing it right at all. Let me go back through and try it again after looking over the chapter...

Comment: No problem, take your time. If you have questions, please post them :)